# pointwise and uniform convergence of $\sum \sqrt{n}\log \frac{(1+x+nx^2)}{1+nx^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

To prove the pointwise convergence $|f_n(x)|=| \sqrt{n} \log \frac{(1+x+nx^2)}{1+nx^2}|\sim$ $\frac{|x|\sqrt{n}}{1+nx^2}$ and $\sum \frac{|x|\sqrt{n}}{1+nx^2}$ don't pointwise converge so there isn't pointwise an uniform convergence of the series?

It's right?

for $x=0$ I have null series so only for $x=0$ I have pointwise an uniform convergence?